# Maven repository for BIRT 2.6.0

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, birt, pom.xml

Is there a Maven repository for BIRT 2.6.0 that I could point to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm working on it. See my [blog for progress](http://blog.pdark.de/2011/03/20/eclipse-3-6-2-artifacts-for-maven-2/) or try the first RC at http://maven.eclipse.org/nexus/content/repositories/testing/.

The project also comes with a set of [tools to convert Eclipse bundles into Maven artifacts](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Tools_4_Eclipse).

Comment: I have some imports for org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.*  I added the dependency for org.eclipse.birt.report.engine, and it doesn't have the api classes in it.  Maybe birt's engineapi.jar is not part of that.  Should it be?

Comment: Yes; I've opened a new bug to track this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357598

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not any. In our project we simply downloaded BIRT runtime and installed all required artifacts in our central repository, and everyone references it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a public repository offering Birt 2.6. The only one I know is:

http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/eclipse/birt/

But the latest version available in there is 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Yet I also couldn't found any Maven repository for retrieve all BIRT related dependencies, but I am using some method to retrieve BIRT related dependencies by configuring Maven properties in pom.xml as follow, please use this URL for more detail http://eclipse.dzone.com/tips/birt-maven

```
<properties>
    <birt.runtime.location>/home/channa/Desktop/birt-runtime-2_6_1/WebViewerExample</birt.runtime.location>
    <birt.runtime.libs>${birt.runtime.location}/WEB-INF/lib</birt.runtime.libs>
    <birt.runtime.platform>${birt.runtime.location}/WEB-INF/platform</birt.runtime.platform>
    <birt.runtime.version>2.6.1</birt.runtime.version>
</properties> 

<!-- BIRT runtime 2.6.1 related dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>${birt.runtime.version}</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${birt.runtime.libs}/axis.jar
    </systemPath>
</dependency>
```