# Why is there no Maven repository for Eclipse Birt 3.7 => There is one for Birt 4.2

Tags: eclipse, maven, birt

Now, since Birt 3.7 has an easier way to use the runtime (just deploy the jars), why is there no maven repository?

Birt contains over 50 dependencies, it's ridiculous.

How do you work around this issue?

**Update:**
Some more help is out there (we are not alone):
https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Embeding+Birt+into+Application+built+with+Maven

**Update 11. Feb. 2012**
In the linked Birt-Exchange Forum there is some progress:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I have't tested myself.

**Update 23. Apr. 2012**
Some more movement (this time on Eclipse side)
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/845370/
=> Looking forward to June, maybe this time.

**Update 11. July 2012**
Still no useful new information from the linked places
For some of you this: http://hartmann-schneevoigt.com/2012/04/04/eclipse-birt-3-7-2-with-maven/ might help. (deploys jar from eclipse to artifactory / nexus, with much less efford)

Here might be the solution:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=258911 (Scroll to bottom)

```xml
<repository>
   <id>sonatype-nexus-releases</id>
   <name>Sonatype Nexus Releases</name>
   <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>
```

**Final Update**
It's official here in Birt 4.2 (Find paragraph 'Maven Support')
http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable4.2.php

Comment: Maybe you can find a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570512/maven-repository-for-birt-2-6-0

Comment: There is a link to a repository with many eclipse artifacts, for some reason there is only Birt 2.6.2. There is no trace of 3.7...

Comment: Some uncoordinated movement here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/261821/757516/ and there http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/24196-mavenizing-birt-3-7-1/page__p__91521&#entry91521__s__6ec86cf585c0a19a34b13cfe1834eacb

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Tools_4_Eclipse 
might help.

There is this: maven.eclipse.org
The official maven repository from eclipse, it even uses dependencies from maven central.

Now it narrows down to: Why is BIRT 3.7 not in eclipse 3.7?

Answer (score 1):

You can find another workaround here: http://hartmann-schneevoigt.com/2012/04/04/eclipse-birt-3-7-2-with-maven/

Basically, in this solution / workaround the `birt` artifacts were uploaded to a local artifact proxy using `maven-eclipse-plugin` and then used as normal maven dependencies, as you would do in general.

All necessary pom snippets and commands are provided, so this should be a short task.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone took the burden:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.orchestra.eclipse.birt

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the artifacts present in Maven Central (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.orchestra.eclipse.birt) are incomplete: for example, they are missing the PDF emitter.

That means you cannot produce PDF, a serious drawback for a reporting engine, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Below maven dependency worked for me perfectly.

```
 <repositories>
  <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-releases</id>
        <name>Sonatype Nexus Releases</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Removed your unnecessary, self-promoting link.