# BIRT over playframework - can't find package?

Tags: playframework, dependencies, playframework-2.0, birt

I've been trying to find a "nice" reporting tool (engine?) to put over the playframework.
After exploring a few options, I've decided to try the BIRT...

Unfortunately i'm finding it impossible to integrate it into the Play on the dependency level !

I added to the /lib directory all BIRT jars (taken from the eclipse plugin folder), compiled, eclipsified (and saw the .classpath was injected with the jars).

but when I try to import say: "org.eclipse.birt.core.*" i'm getting:

```
[info] Loading project definition from D:\dev\Play\reporting\project
[info] Set current project to reporting (in build file:/D:/dev/Play/reporting/)
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to D:\dev\Play\reporting\target\scala-2.9.1\classes...
[error] D:\dev\Play\reporting\app\controllers\Application.java:8: package org.eclipse.birt.core does not exist
[error] import org.eclipse.birt.core.*;
[error] ^
[error] 1 error
[error] {file:/D:/dev/Play/reporting/}reporting/compile:compile: javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Could not create Eclipse project files:
[error] Error evaluating task 'dependency-classpath': error
```

on the other hand, tried another jar... like google's collect, and it worked...

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: b.t.w. - I'm using the play 2.0.2, eclipse 4.2, BIRT 4.2

Answer (score 0):

In general I would recommend to use the dependency-management. See 
[Why is there no Maven repository for Eclipse Birt 3.7 => There is one for Birt 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245565/why-is-there-no-maven-repository-for-eclipse-birt-3-7-there-is-one-for-birt-4)
and [Maven repository for BIRT 2.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570512/maven-repository-for-birt-2-6-0)
Are you sure the lib approach work?

Comment: ThanX for the reply, I dropped the subject for a while but 3 days ago found the answer for BIRT 3.7.2 or 4.2- after putting the "RUNTIME" jars in the lib and tinkering a little with the code - got it running...