# A project that outputs a POM

Tags: maven-2, birt

I am new to Maven and I'm trying to convert a web project to Maven build-able.  My project has a dependency on the eclipse's BIRT reporting engine 2.6.  I cannot find a public repository with a satisfactory BIRT pom, which is very sad because BIRT has TONS of dependencies (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570512/maven-repository-for-birt-2-6-0), and my comment under the answer for more details).  Is there some way that I can create a maven project that contains all of the BIRT .jars, and at build-time will output a pom, in which I can declare as a dependency in my web project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a pom similar to [this one](http://maven.eclipse.org/nexus/content/repositories/testing/org/eclipse/birt/org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples/2.6.2/org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples-2.6.2.pom), which would list all the BIRT dependencies you need, but have the packaging as 'pom'. Then you declare a dependency on this pom and you will get those dependencies.

Comment: thanks for your help with this. Would I need to `mvn install:install-file` all of the files to my local repository.  Would it be better to setup a repository manager such as nexus, to install them to?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Provided your Maven settings point to a repo holding the BIRT artifacts, any build that uses a BIRT artifact should trigger a download of the BIRT artifact to your local repo.